# JOIN two tables while grouping by an index and maching for multiple foreign ids

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have the 3 Following Tables:

objects:

```
ObjectID ObjectDescription
1        "first"
2        "second"
```

attributes:

```
AttributeID AttributeDescription
1           "att1"
2           "att2"
3           "att3"
4           "att4"
```

attributelink:

```
AttributeID ObjectID
1           1
2           1
4           1
```

Now my question: I want now have some attributes selected and want to know, which Object has all my selected Attributes. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
    INNER JOIN `attributelink` 
         ON `objects`.`ObjectID` = `attributelink`.`ObjectID`
    WHERE `attributelink`.`AttributeID` =1 AND `attributelink`.`AttributeID` =2  
GROUP BY `objects`.`ObjectID`
```

That obviously doesn't work, because one row can't have 2 AttributeIDs, but how can I archieve this?

Comment: if you select 2 attributes, then u want objects to list the objects which has these two attributes? So in the WHERE clause, use the two attributes. Then use a GROUP BY function to group on objects, to fetch the objects whose count(attributes) =2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join on the `attributelink` table once for each selected attribute you want to check for:

```
SELECT o.ObjectID
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN attributelink a1 ON o.ObjectID = a1.ObjectID AND a1.AttributeID = 1
INNER JOIN attributelink a2 ON o.ObjectID = a2.ObjectID AND a2.AttributeID = 2
GROUP BY o.ObjectID
```

Your test data doesn't show a whole lot about whether it works or not, but FWIW, [here's the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77dcb/1).

---

Another way to do it is to use `COUNT DISTINCT` with `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77dcb/2)):

```
SELECT o.ObjectID
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN attributelink a ON o.ObjectID = a.ObjectID
WHERE a.AttributeID IN (1,2) --here you filter the rows on the attributes to test
GROUP BY o.ObjectID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(a.AttributeID)) = 2 --# of attributes, means "having ALL"
```