# querying 2 tables to find results

Tags: mysql

I have a table of submissions with field called submissionID (primary key) in it

I have a table of answers with a field called submissionID in it

My goal is to find submissionIDs where 16 and 39 were both answered

Below is what i have so far but doesnt seem to be doing what i want... maybe im on the wrong path with JOIN? maybe i need an inner select?

```
SELECT submissions.*, answer.answer, answer.submissionID FROM submissions JOIN answer USING(submissionID) WHERE (answer = 16 AND answer = '39')
```

HERE IS THE SCHEME FOR THE TABLE SUBMISSIONS

```
CREATE TABLE `submissions` (
  `submissionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sendInfoTo` text NOT NULL,
  `userIP` text NOT NULL,
  `sendNotificationTo` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`submissionID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1343314525 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

9'
```

HEREE IS THE SCHEME FOR ANSWERS

```
CREATE TABLE `answer` (
  `aID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `qtID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `submissionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56247 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

submission table holds the unique submission id

the answer table holds all the answers from the submission

so for example i have a bunch of questions.  the answer to question 1 could be 16 and the answer to question 2 could be 39 so i want to find submissionID's where 16 and 39 were both answered

Comment: is there a reason that 39 is being treated as a string in your query? (answer = '39' rather than answer = 39)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674636/join-two-tables-while-grouping-by-an-index-and-maching-for-multiple-foreign-ids/11674668#11674668 which I *just* answered.

Comment: actually, condition `answer = 16 AND answer = 39` is never true, isn't it? :]

Comment: there are probably lots of answers where one or the other was answered but i only want to know the submissionID's that answered both

Comment: +1 with @KubaWyrostek unless you provide us with a schema of your tables. How can one column `answer` have both 16 & 39 at the same time in your `answer` table?

Comment: so your `answer` column is `text` and how are you storing a record of the ones answered? will it like "16,xx,39" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    submissions.*
    , answer.answer
    , answer.submissionID 
FROM 
    submissions 
JOIN answer on submissions.submissionID = answer.submissionID
WHERE
    answer.answer IN (16,39)
```

Comment: I need to know where both were answered by a submissionID not if one or the other was answered

Comment: How can one column answer have both 16 & 39 at the same time in your answer table? Can you provide the schema for the tables?

Answer (score 0):

try the following query , this might help you ..

```
SELECT s.submissionID  FROM submissions s JOIN answer a USING(submissionID) WHERE a.answer IN (16,39)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you AND condition for answer =18 and answer =39 never be true, you can go for OR in following way:

```
  SELECT submissions.*, answer.answer, answer.submissionID FROM submissions JOIN answer ON  submissions.submissionID = answer.submissionID WHERE answer.answer ='16' OR answer.answer ='39'
```

Comment: like the other answers this seems to be return submissionID's where it found 16 or 39 but i need to know that a submissionID answer both